# Change button Image on click

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I change the image of a button when I click it?

I have a button and at an early stage I want it with an icon, but when I click it (active) and icon is replaced by another.

How can I do this?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gasrqs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<!-- image1 -->
<a><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/Gwo.svg' title='' /></a>

<p></p>

<!-- image2 -->
<a style="display:none"><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/Gw7.svg' title='' /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do so using just one line:

```
<a><img 
    [src]="toggle ? 'https://svgshare.com/i/Gwo.svg' : 'https://svgshare.com/i/Gw7.svg'" 
    title='' 
    (click)='toggle = !toggle'/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like that:

**TS file**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  value = 'https://svgshare.com/i/Gwo.svg'; //default_value

  updateImage() {
    this.value = 'https://svgshare.com/i/Gw7.svg';
  }
}
```

**HTML file**

```
<a><img [src]="value" title='' (click)='updateImage()' /></a>
```

You can also update the image each time you click on the button not just the first time using the attribute status like this:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  value = 'https://svgshare.com/i/Gwo.svg'; //default_value
  status = false;


  updateImage() {
    this.status = !this.status;
    if (this.status) //active status
     this.value = 'https://svgshare.com/i/Gw7.svg';
    else this.value = 'https://svgshare.com/i/Gwo.svg';
  }

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I updated the solution to handle also the multi-click case on the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can update svg attributes on click as well as swapping the image.

For example if you had

```
 <svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
   <circle id="circle1" onclick='changerect(evt)' r="30" cx="34" cy="34" style="fill: red; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2" />
 </svg>
```

You could use js to update the fill, stroke width, opacity etc.. using a function.

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 3.5in; height: 1in">
   <circle id="circle1" onclick='changesvg(evt)' r="30" cx="34" cy="34" style="fill: red; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 2" />
 </svg>

<script>
  function changesvg(evt) {
    var svgobj = evt.target;
    svgobj.style.stroke = 'yellow';
    svgobj.style.opacity = 0.5;
  }
</script>
```

If you wanted to swap images on click you could just use a regular swap image as ic_paty has outlined above.

Comment: you'd probably only use the js if the images were similar, but still.. good to know..imho

Comment: Question is regarding angular, so the answer should also be in angular format.

Comment: @Plochie I'm sure OP can figure out ng-click on his/her own.. StackOverflow is only meant to be a guide, not a code-writing service after all!

Comment: IMO, the whole point of answer is to clear the doubts. BTW in angular its `(click)`, and in angularjs it was `ng-click`. Also angular has classes which does not have `function` prefix.